# pyinstaller importerror when module is in the same directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Pyinstaller recently stopped importing a module that it previously had no problem with so I set up a simple test case to isolate the problem.

I created a script (pt.py) as follows:

```
import py_script1
import py_script
print('hello world')
```

py_script.py and py_script1.py are identical and located in the same directory as pt.py. They both import os, random and math and have some functions in them.

When running pyinstaller with default settings it compiles the .exe file but when I try to run it, I get "ImportError: No module named py_script". Checking the warnings text file shows that it was never compiled into the .exe file.

Changing the order of the imports doesn't help - I get the same error. I have also tried to uninstall and reinstall pyinstaller but that has not helped

How is this even possible - the two imported scripts are identical and are located in the same place!

More importantly how do I fix this problem?

PyInstaller 3.3.1
Python 3.3.5 
Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Despite the misleading exception description I isolated the problem as the following line in the imported file:

SB_CONSTANT = 0.00000005670373 #Stefan–Boltzmann constant (W/m2/K4)

For some reason this number broke pyinstaller. I changed it to:

SB_CONSTANT = 5.6704e-8

...and the module imported fine.